# Horizontal and vertical navigationbar

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for my schoolproject. I want an horizontal-navigation-bar and an diagonal-navigation-bar.

But the problem is, when I scroll on a page, the horizontal-navigation-bar scrolls with it.

What would be the best solution for this problem?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
    width: 100%; height: 100%
    
}

.main-page {
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-left:  14em;
    position: relative;
}

.horizontal {
    list-style: none;
}
.horizontal ul {
        
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

.horizontal li {
        float: left;
    }

.horizontal li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.horizontal li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
    }

.horizontal .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
    
    

.diagonalNavigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10em;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.diagonalNavigation li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.diagonalNavigation li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.diagonalNavigation li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.php">PositivePower</a></li>
        <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="diagonalNavigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="nieuws.php">Nieuws</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">Over mij</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="beheerbestelling.php">Beheer bestelling</a></li>-->
        <!--        <li><a href="krachttraining.php">krachttraining</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="gegevenswijzigen.php">wijzig gegevens</a></li>-->
        <!--        <li><a href="kickboxen.php">kickboksen</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="Winkelwagen.php">Winkelwagen</a></li>
        <li><a href="sportvoeding.php">Sportvoeding</a></li>
        <li><a href="successtories.php">succesverhalen</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="informatieaanvraag.php">Informatie aanvragen</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="gastenboek.php">gastenboek</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="gastenboek.php">Gastenboek</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="registreren.php">Registreren</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="administrator.php">Administrator</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="beheerbestelling.php">Mijn Bestelling</a></li>-->
    </ul>
</div>
<section class="main-page">
  
  <h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
<h1>welkom</h1>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out. I commented all the lines i added so you know what each line does. But i would recommend Organizing you HTML better, and probably use class names for each `ul` since it will help you style them better later on. And instead of using margin to much, try using flex box.. It i will save you lots of time.

```css
/*Revove this when finished testing scroll*/

.main-page{
  height: 3334px
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
    width: 100%; height: 100%;

}

.main-page {
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-left:  14em;
    position: relative;
}

.horizontal {
    list-style: none;
    /*set bar position to fixed so that it always stays at the top*/
    position: fixed;
    /*defined bar height to 50px*/
    height: 50px;
    /*set bar width to 100vw so that bar always fills up the viewport*/
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 999;
}
.horizontal ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

.horizontal li {
        float: left;
    }
.horizontal ul ul{

  float: right;  /*Added This to align about and login in horizontal Bar*/
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.horizontal li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.horizontal li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
    }

.horizontal .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }

.diagonalNavigation{
    position: absolute;
  /*Set height of vertical bar to 100vh so it always remains the same no matter the viewport*/

  height: 100vh;
  /* defined bar width to 140px*/
  width: 140px;
  /*move bar 50px height of horizontal bar so that it is HOME link is visible*/
  top: 50px;


}

.diagonalNavigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10em;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.diagonalNavigation li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.diagonalNavigation li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.diagonalNavigation li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.php">PositivePower</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="diagonalNavigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="nieuws.php">Nieuws</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">Over mij</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="beheerbestelling.php">Beheer bestelling</a></li>-->
        <!--        <li><a href="krachttraining.php">krachttraining</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="gegevenswijzigen.php">wijzig gegevens</a></li>-->
        <!--        <li><a href="kickboxen.php">kickboksen</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="Winkelwagen.php">Winkelwagen</a></li>
        <li><a href="sportvoeding.php">Sportvoeding</a></li>
        <li><a href="successtories.php">succesverhalen</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="informatieaanvraag.php">Informatie aanvragen</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="gastenboek.php">gastenboek</a></li>-->
        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="gastenboek.php">Gastenboek</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="registreren.php">Registreren</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="administrator.php">Administrator</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="beheerbestelling.php">Mijn Bestelling</a></li>-->
    </ul>
</div>
<section class="main-page">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your top navigation bar position set to absolute. 
I believe its the 'horrizontal' class

Then
Set the top:0; left:0; right:0;

Theres actually a couple ways you can do this. The above answer will give you what youre looking for but might not be the style youre going for your website.

Comment: When I do that, the vertical navigation-bar goes on top of the horizontal navigation-bar :/

Comment: And the horizontal navigation bar scrolls with the page itself. I want both navigation-bars to be fixed.

Comment: You would then have to put an absolute position on the vertical navigation bar with the top attribute being spaced out so it doesnt overlap. Honestly it seems like you are just coding it a little bit weird. When you scroll on the content with all the h1 tags your horizontal navigation should have no relation to the scroll movement. You have to section off you website differently.

Comment: You can make your navigation bar as 'position:fixed'

Comment: Also looking at your CSS code you have no actual definition for the diagonalNavigation class. You just have templates for child elements. Also, maybe try changing the main-page section to just a div tag.

Comment: You should not be having to put margins so much on your 'main-page' class; Its supposed to just fit in the remaining space left over from your navigation bars. Maybe put the vertical navigation a width of i.e. 20% then put the 'main-page' to 80%; with the height being the remaining height from the horizontal navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks all for helping me :)